# Cannot assign to the result of this expression while assigning CGRect

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move an SKShapeNode by overriding the touchesMoved method. While setting the new frame to the shape node, I come across the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression". What is the cause? It worked just fine when it was in Objective C

```
        override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    //Get touch coordinates in location view
    var touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var touchPoint : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    // new frame with new location
    var newFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - offsetX, touchPoint.y - offsetY, myShapeNode.frame.width, myShapeNode.frame.height);


    //Set the new frame
    myShapeNode.frame = newFrame
}
```

I actually was able to get it to work by using this

```
    myShapeNode.position = CGPointMake(newFrame.origin.x, newFrame.origin.y)
```

But I want to know why the previous code wasn't working

Comment: Setting myShapeNode.position changes the position of the shape node which is what you want. Setting the myShapeNode.frame would change the position and the size, which is apparently not what you want (and it's not allowed). If you would like to change the size as well, set myShapeNode.size to CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight).

Answer (score 0):

That would be because the `frame` property of an SKNode is read-only, which means you can't assign to it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/frame

Comment: There is nothing to work around. The `frame` is just a description of the boundaries. Lots of properties are read-only. That's life. What's the problem?